# Python 3 Scope between classes in separate files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, variables, scope

I have been researching for ages and cannot find this specific question being asked (so perhaps I am missing something simple!) but I have had trouble separating classes into different .py files.

Scenario:

Main class imports a Settings class file and a Work class file..Settings class populates a list with objects instantiated from an Object class file...

Work class wants to cycle through that list and change values within each of those objects. <-- here is where I come unstuck.

I have tried it by making the values class variables rather than instance. Still I have to import the settings class in the work class in order to write the code to access the value to change. But it wont change the instance of that class within the main class where all these classes are called!

I read an article on Properties. The examples they gave were still examples of different classes within the same file.

Any advice as to what I should be looking at would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I was doing to test it out:

Main File where all will be run from:

```
import Set_Test
import Test_Code

sting = Set_Test.Settings()
tc = Test_Code.Testy()

ID = sting._settingsID
print(f'Settings ID is: {ID}')

tc.changeVal()

ID = sting._settingsID
print(f'Settings ID is: {ID}')
```

Set_Test.py:

```
class Settings:

    def __init__(self):
        self._settingsID = 1

    @property
    def settingsID(self):
        return self._settingsID

    @settingsID.setter
    def settingsID(self, value):
        self.settingsID = value
```

Test_Code.py:

```
import Set_Test

class Testy:

    def changeVal(self):
        Set_Test.Settings.settingsID = 8
```

Comment: Right, but what exactly is the issue? What behavior are you seeing, and what did you expect?

Comment: I would like the changeVal method in Test_Code to change the value of the settingsID in Set_Test. So on the second print it should print the new value.

Comment: @Ripfury This should read `self._settingsID = value`, note the underscore

Comment: as it is it just prints 1 instead of 8

Comment: @Ripfury And this `Set_Test.Settings.settingsID = 8` results in a `class variable` not as expected changing the value of the instance variable.

Comment: @stovfl thanks but yeah still has same effect.

Comment: @stovfl ahh so perhaps I should set it up as a class variable in first place? I was trying to follow the end of this property tutorial [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)

Comment: @Ripfury The tutorial dosn't use 2 classes, therefore you have to change to `.changeVal(sting)` and use the reference `sting.settingsID = 8`

Comment: Thanks a lot @stovfl ...you saved a life! :D

Comment: Note, your `property` is totally pointless. use a normal attribute

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga example please?

Comment: Just use `self.settingsID = 1` (notice no underscores) in `__init__` and delete the properties. You don't need them.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga then I would have to define set and get methods in order for a seperate class in seperate file to interact. That's not pythonic and creates a ton more code on the other end when getting and setting. If you could actually demonstrate the code that you think is correct this might be clearer... but this property method is working fine right now.

Comment: @Ripfury no, absolutely you would not need to define set or get methods for classes in separate modules to interact.What gave you that idea? Literally just delete your getters and setters, and change your `__init__` to use `self.settingsID` instead of `self._settingsID`, and the rest of your code will function exactly the same. [Here's what I mean](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/a1fc3deb6c2bcde2d25a35d309aa2982)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to stovfl who provided the answer in comments. I managed to decipher what stovfl meant eventually :D

I think!

Well the below code works for anyone who wants to know:

Main:

```
import Set_Test
import Test_Code

sting = Set_Test.Settings()
tc = Test_Code.Testy()

ID = sting._settingsID
print(f'Settings ID is: {ID}')

tc.changeVal(sting)

ID = sting._settingsID
print(f'Settings ID is: {ID}')
```

Set_Test.py:

```
class Settings:

    def __init__(self):
        self._settingsID = 1

    @property
    def settingsID(self):
        return self._settingsID

    @settingsID.setter
    def settingsID(self, value):
        self._settingsID = value
```

Test_Code.py

```
import Set_Test
sting = Set_Test.Settings()

class Testy():

    def changeVal(self, sting):
        print(sting.settingsID)
        sting.settingsID = 8
        print(sting.settingsID)
```